# Nigerian Math Olympiad Question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math

How many ways can a child who is given the task of laying *n* bricks lay them out they can do so under the conditions

- The laying of bricks is constrained to a single vertical plane
- The bricks must be either placed adjacent to the previously placed brick or directly above it
- The child constructs the initial layer from left to right
- No brick can be floating

All cases with 6 blocks

[image]

**My attempt:** I just thought of this as a case of **partitioning**  *n*, if I find the number of ways to partition *n*, I know the structures they make since after partitioning I just arrange the numbers in descending order and that would be it.

However I haven't come across any such formula that states the number of partitions a number *n* can have, I think it may be that my solution is wrong somehow since this was asked in the Nigeran math Olympiad a few years ago (saw it on AOPS) and the answers are almost always a complete formula in these kinds of tests, instead of statements. So is my answer right or wrong?

Comment: Yes, this is effectively partitioning.

Comment: Do you have a link to the original AoPS page and/or a more specific reference to which Nigerian Mathematical Olympiad it was?

Comment: Is that diagram your attempt all the cases, or the original question's list.  Other patterns may be allowed such as $\,_\square^\square\,_\square^{\,}\,_\square^\square\,_\square^{\,}$ distinct from $\,_\square^{\,}\,_\square^{\,}\,_\square^\square\,_\square^\square$

Comment: @Henry: I don't think that the pattern that you suggest is possible, because one of the rules is that "The bricks must be either placed adjacent to the previously placed brick or directly above it", which implies (among other things) that each row must be contiguous. By the way, how did you arrange those boxes so beautifully?

Comment: @ruakh That is LaTeX.   If  bricks must be either placed adjacent to *the* previously placed brick or directly above it then there are many fewer options:  $\,_\square^{\,}\,_\square^{\,}\,_\square^\square\,_\square^\square$ fails that rule.  If they can be placed adjacent to *a* previously placed brick or directly above it, or if they can be placed adjacent to the previous brick and then fall to the ground, then there are more such as $\,_\square^\square\,_\square^{\,}\,_\square^\square\,_\square^{\,}$

Comment: @Henry: I know the basics of LaTeX, but I tried using `\begin{align}`, `\begin{matrix}`, and a few other things, and none of them came out so nicely as your arrangements. Would you mind sharing your specific input? (You can wrap your code in backticks -- the ` character -- to "escape" it so that it shows the actual code instead of the math output.) I'll reply to your relevant point once I'm capable of drawing readable diagrams. :-)

Comment: @ruakh `\,_\square^{\,}\,_\square^{\,}\,_\square^\square\,_\square^\square` gives $\,_\square^{\,}\,_\square^{\,}\,_\square^\square\,_\square^\square$.  Right-click - Show Math As - TeX commands would show you this.  Only works for two rows

Comment: @Henry: Aha! Thank you so much! So -- you can build $\,_\square^{\,}\,_\square^{\,}\,_\square^\square\,_\square^\square$, while following that rule, by placing blocks in this order: $_\fbox{1}^{\,} \, _\fbox{2}^{\,} \, _\fbox{3}^\fbox{6} \, _\fbox{4}^\fbox{5}$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Observations towards a solution.
Prove the following. If you're stuck, state what you've tried.

- The total number of blocks in the structure is $n$.
- Every layer must be built one at a time (since we can't go down)
- The structure is uniquely determined by how many squares is in each horizontal layer.
- The number of blocks in each horizontal layer (2nd onwards)has at most as many blocks as the layer beneath it.
- Thus, when viewed in horizontal layers, a structure yields a partition of $n$.
- Conversely, show that if we have a partition of $n$, then we can build a structure.
- Thus, we have a bijection. So, the number of structures is indeed the number of partitions.

I agree with you that no closed-form expression is known, so that likely isn't what they were expecting.
Maybe check the original writeup (see if they were asked to prove it's the number of partitions). It might also be possible that they got the problem wrong.

Comment: “No closed form expression is known” — however, there are established names and notations for these numbers, which the problem authors could perhaps have been thinking of?  I’ve usually heard them called the *partition numbers*, the terminology used in the [OEIS, A000041](https://oeis.org/A000041); Wikipedia calls them the *[partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory))* and denotes them by $p(n)$.  For comparison, I don’t think Olympiad problem authors would hesitate to use Catalan numbers $C_n$ in a solution.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine What you said is correct, but what Calvin said is still correct. There are no nice closed form (well there are some insane Ramanujan infinite series things but) for partition numbers.

Comment: @GarethMa: Absolutely, I don’t disagree with Calvin’s excellent answer, especially about nonexistence of a nice closed form — just speculating that the problem-setters might have considered this function “standard” enough to use in their intended solution.

Answer (score 4):

The structure is built in a zig-zag - choose in one layer how far to go to the right (say) before going up; then in the next layer you can choose how far to go to the left, up to a maximum of the width of the previous layer, before going up; then repeat. This is why the number of structures is equal to the number of partitions of $n$: any pile of rows of squares with the number of squares in each row at most the number in the row below (a partition) can be turned into a zig-zag by moving each row horizontally so the rightmost square in it is above the rightmost square in the row below, or the leftmost square is above the leftmost square in the row below, alternating between these.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: this is in fact the number of partitions. A partition of 6 is a list of numbers without order, something like $6=2+2+1+1$, not a choice of where to put dividers into a line of six balls, like $\cdot|\cdot\cdot|\cdot\cdot|\cdot$.

I would approach this problem using a recursive function. You can do this with a recursive function. The only choice you can make in each row is how many bricks to place in that row. Each choice leads to a sub-problem, where you place a smaller number of bricks, and you also have a constraint on the maximum number of bricks in the "new first row" (i.e. the actual second row).

Can you see a way to set up the recursion? And can you work out the initial conditions (one initial condition for $n$ bricks with a previous-row width of 1 row, and another initial condition for 0 bricks with a previous-row width of $r$ rows)?

Once you have your recursion and initial conditions, you can set up your table of values. Once you get a few rows in, see if you can see the pattern in the diagonal entries (those for $n$ bricks with a previous-row width of $n$ bricks). I haven't found a pattern yet, but my numbers were 1,2,3,5,7,11,15,22,30, ...

Comment: which is the start of the sequence of [numbers of partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Partition_function)

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood the definition of the number of partitions.

Answer (score 1):

It is not partitioning, because in the partition diagrams, the height is monotonic left to right.

The solution can be written thus:

Suppose the bottom layer has $k$ bricks. Then the number of ways is the number of ways to put $n-k$ bricks in $k$ bins, which is ${n-1}\choose{k-1}.$ Now, $k$ can be anything from $1$ to $n,$ so we have the sum
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n-1}{k-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}k= 2^{n-1}.$$

Comment: I got the exact same result before but erased it since it didn't match the diagrams, perhaps you overlooked the fact that the bricks must be kept adjacent to the previously placed brick, or that the number of bricks in each successive level is less than that of the previous level? If you didn't then can you kindly explain how you got (n−1 C k−1.)  please.

Comment: "Then the number of ways is the number of ways to put n−k bricks in k bins" not obviously.

Comment: (I agree it's not just a partition you look at it vertically) Your approach doesn't quite make sense to me. EG for $n=5$, and a ground layer of $k=3$, you can't form a stack of 2, 1, 2.

Comment: @AadiSinha It says "The child constructs the initial layer from left to right" not "bricks must be kept adjacent to the previously placed brick" for all layers.  So this solution essentially puts the initial layer down of width $k$ and then stacks upwards form each base brick a total of ${n-1\choose k}$ ways

Comment: An alternative argument is split the $n$ blocks so $n=a+b+\cdots+d$ and then put $a$ in the first tower, $b$ in the second, ... and $d$ in the last.  There are $n-1$ gaps for possible splits and so $2^{n-1}$ possible patterns

Comment: @Henry It *does* say "bricks must be either placed adjacent to the previously placed brick or directly above it". Think of it as a "snake", like in [Nibbles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibbles_(video_game)), where the snake starts horizontally from the left (and can't leave empty cells beneath its trace). Calvin's answer is correct, and you indeed get the number of partitions, even though the figures are not partition diagrams : it doesn't matter, because you can't choose the side from which each layer starts: it will be alternately left / right / left / right....